# Ftp Upload of Large File causes VB.Net App to Hang on Stream.Close()

Tags: vb.net, file, upload, freeze, ftpwebrequest

I'm trying to upload a large file (over 50Mb) to my webserver but my app hangs when trying to close the stream. If the file uploaded is larger than 50Mb then the .Close() causes it to hang - no error message at all - however a file less than 50Mb succeeds.

What do you suggest to get around the fstream.Close() hanging my app?

```
Dim target As New Uri(uploadedFilePath)
Dim fRequest As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(target)
fRequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(usr, pswd)
fRequest.KeepAlive = False
fRequest.Proxy = Nothing
fRequest.UsePassive = True
fRequest.UseBinary = True
fRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
fRequest.Timeout = 180000

Dim count As Integer = 0
Dim readBytes As Integer = 0
Const bufferLength As Integer = 8192
Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(bufferLength - 1) {}
Dim fs As FileStream = File.OpenRead(localFileName)
Dim fStream As Stream = fRequest.GetRequestStream
Console.WriteLine("Writing bytes to the stream. {0}", String.Format("{0:HH:mm}", Now))
Do
    readBytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength)
    fStream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes)
    count += readBytes
Loop While readBytes <> 0
Console.WriteLine("Writing {0} bytes to the stream. {1}", count, String.Format("{0:HH:mm}", Now))
fStream.Close()
Console.WriteLine("fstream Closed {0}", String.Format("{0:HH:mm}", Now))
```

which gives the output as:

```
Writing bytes to the stream. 13:08

Writing 51391500 bytes to the stream. 13:18
```

Note the last Console.Writeline is never output.

PS  Using Visual Studio 2010 and .Net Framework 4.0

Comment: Can you successfully FTP a file bigger than 50mb to the server using a regular FTP client program?

Comment: Most definitely.  Regularly have to put up a 150Mb file - hence the desire to automate this - given the other function of this app is to generate that 150Mb file.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem. I'm tearing my hair out trying to find the solution!!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you didn't close the input filestream (fs).  I have a process that FTPs a file and then moves it to a 'successful' folder.  Because fs wasn't closed, I got a "file being used by another process" when I tried to move it.  I caught it in a Try-catch.  I'm not sure if that is it, since you say 50MB files succeed, but it's a thought.

I'm going to put in the `fs.close()` and see if that takes care of my error.  I moved a 189MB file, which took some time with the connection I was using... but it seemed to work right up until the move.

Answer (score 0):

So, did the file itself arrive at the FTP? If so, a workaround would be to just cut the process at this given moment, and leave it be.

Have you tried fiddling around with the settings?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may just need to increase the timeout.

Put a `Try-Catch` outside the loop to trap the error being returned, you may find the error is:

> underlying connection was closed

Hope that helps!